# Full build of modernizr3?

Tags: nuget, modernizr

I'm using modernizr in my ASP.net MVC application, and I'd like to use the `inputformaction` detect added in Modernizr v3.  The latest version available on nuget is [2.8.3](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Modernizr/).  So that means I need to add it independently from nuget.  There doesn't seem to be any official full build.

The only thing I can find on their website is [Download](https://modernizr.com/download?), which prompts me to create a custom build.  If I select the features I'm using now, then I'll need to come back to this website every time I want a new detect, and remember all the options I chose last time.  That's not really practical.  I've also found that you can make custom builds using a node package and a .json definition file.  I don't really feel like installing node just for this if I can avoid it.

All I want is a complete build of modernizr.  Is there any way to do it other than writing a script to check all the checkboxes on their download page?

Comment: I believe [this](https://modernizr.com/download?applicationcache-audio-backgroundsize-borderimage-borderradius-boxshadow-canvas-canvastext-cssanimations-csscolumns-cssgradients-cssreflections-csstransforms-csstransforms3d-csstransitions-flexbox-flexboxlegacy-fontface-forcetouch-generatedcontent-geolocation-hashchange-history-hsla-indexeddb-inlinesvg-input-inputtypes-localstorage-multiplebgs-opacity-postmessage-rgba-sessionstorage-smil-svg-svgclippaths-textshadow-touchevents-video-webgl-websockets-websocketsbinary-websqldatabase-setclasses) is about as close as you can get to the NuGet version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "complete" build of Modernizr. While it may be a minor inconvenience for you to rebuild when you need new detects, it can cost your users tons of time and money downloading and running javascript that is completely unneeded. There are a bunch of tools that will automate the custom build for you (bower, npm, grunt-modernizr, gulp-modernizr).

If you want a build that contains all of the options - which again is huge and horrible on perf, you can use https://modernizr.com/download?do_not_use_in_production

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted to hear, but I understand why the decision was made.  I don't really want to add another tool into our build process, so I think I will manually determine which detects we are using and find some way of storing that list so we can update and re-build if needed.